# Spring-Batch:Skip records from reading

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

Trying to read data from flat file where I need to skip invalid records inside reader.

How can this be achieved?

Issue: when I return null from T doRead() method for invalid record it stops reading file from there on.

Any help here appreciated.

Comment: typically you'd skip such a record in the processor. Is that an option for you?

Comment: Line mapper tries to match the line length now I might get record with improper length may be less or more characters. Can we do something that we skip mapping of that particular line. Isn't it possible. So that line mapper do not have to do work for invalid records. Please suggest.

Comment: What does Skip invalid records mean? Invalid due to business logic or for invalid syntax/structure/records sequence ?

Comment: syntax/structure/sequence etc..

Comment: the only choice is to throw a custom exception; I used the same strategy to invalidate records sequence when sequence doesn't follow rules specified by a FSM

Comment: instead,if you need lenght field validation or some other checks do that into [processor](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/validator/ValidatingItemProcessor.html)

Comment: Agree with validating data in processor, however I ended up in situation where in I have correct data but the length of the record (say 10 char additional filler) in which case processor will process the record. Can not overcome this. A dirty solution would be to ignore it by faking with a blank record and keep track of such records some how. How does it sound?

Comment: The right solution is to check record fields length into processor and skip record from processor returning null.

Comment: Solved it within chunk processing tasklet with the help of <batch:skippable-exception-classes>
                  <batch:include class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileParseException"/>
            </batch:skippable-exception-classes>

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways to solve this problem, the most common solution its set a number of lines thar could be wrong(invalid), so when you configure the chunks there is a property called "skip-limit", if you dont set this property by default its cero(0), thats the problem is happening with you. example:

```
<tasklet>
<chunk reader="reader" writer="writer" commit-interval="20" skip-limit="500">
<skippable-exception-classes>
<include class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileParseException" />
</skippable-exception-classes>
</chunk>
</tasklet>
```